# Can't get CKEditor to work Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have set it up in the libraries folder, WYSIWYG is under modules. Both are enabled, I have set users, cleared my cache and browser cache, set WYSIWYG profiles, selected CKEditor for Full HTML, added buttons and it's not just there when I go to edit??

I'm lost spent quite a bit of time on this now - any suggestions would be great

Comment: Errors in js? Did you create the textarea field programmatically or using Drupal UI?

Answer (score 0):

I installed CKEditor module, CKEditor library, and then had to hack the CKEditor library folder by creating new subdirectories with the appropriate files (it was looking for the skin and language files in the wrong directory within the CKEditor library folder)...

I'm using the latest version of everything - why is this happening? I would have thought since this happened to me its happening to everyone else as well!

If anyone else has this problem, ensure you have these files in your /modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/ folder: "lang/en-gb.js" "skins/kama/images/sprites.png" "skins/kama/editor.css" "skins/kama/icons.png"

All these files are just in the root folder by default for some reason.

Comment: Is yours working ok now? I'll check that now, I don't know why mine is not, I have all the latest versions too!

Comment: I have ckeditor under 'libraries' rather than modules. I'm trying to run ckeditor on WYSIWYG module - proving to be quite annoying although have no idea why!!